# Vis.js Network could not display icons when using fontawesome-pro-5.0.3

Tags: font-awesome-5, vis.js-network

I recently upgrade fontawesome from version 4.7.0 to pro-5.0.3, the icons in my network chart display as blank box. It works perfectly if I change fontawesome back to 4.7.0. I put my nodes definition codes below, I did a lot of research but couldn't figure it out, thanks very much for any help!

```
nodes.add({
id: Number(dataAjaxArray[i].id),
shape: 'icon',
icon: { face: 'FontAwesome', code: '\uf233', size: 20, color: '#000000' },
iconFontFace: 'FontAwesome',
iconSize: 21,
label: dataAjaxArray[i].name,
font: { size: 11, color: '#4d4d4d', face: 'arial' }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was looking into the same problem. Found that the new version of Font Awesome (5.x) requires a different face attribute in Vis.js.

See https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3916 for the complete explanation. The face attribute now depends on which version of Font Awesome you are using. For the pro version is needs to be

```js
icon: { face: '"Font Awesome 5 Pro Regular"', code: '\uf233', size: 20, color: '#000000' }
```

For the free version it needs to be

```js
icon: { face: '"Font Awesome 5 Free"', code: '\uf233', size: 20, color: '#000000' }
```

See the Vis.js github issue above for other face types for Font Awesome 5.x

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, I think your comments is the correct solution!

Comment: Working for regular icon, but cannot use the icons belonging to  "fas" class

Comment: I am using this `icon: {face: "Font Awesome 5 Free", code: "\ufbb", color: "#6cf7a2", size: 30}`, but still not getting the icon https://fontawesome.com/icons/address-card?style=solid